How to enable tooltip to show helper information for function, method, variables in NvChad?
now, i'm learning to use neovim using NvChad,
but i don't know how to showing a tooltip helper like this

after write code.
before in vscode, if i hover to code example console.log(), vs code show information about console.log.
how to showing a tooltip information about console.log in my nvchad, Are there any plugins I should install?
my nvchad is new installation and not added another plugins
show a tooltip information like vscode
